# pivot does not work when using a nested select in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a requirement to pivot the columns of a particular table specified from a user.
 the problem is the number of columns from each table to pivot is dynamic.
so the code below gets the name of the columns from the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                LISTAGG('''' || column_name || '''', ',') 
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) AS temp_in_statement 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'DIM_XYZ')
```

the code above returns the columns in the following format:

```
col1, col2
```

I have to use a pivot for this requirement and plug the code above in the code below in order to pivot the columns.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE
      table_name = 'DIM_XYZ'

)
PIVOT
(
  MIN(column_name)
  FOR column_name IN ( 

-- values added manually 

 'col1','col2'

-- values added manually 


    )
)
ORDER BY table_name;
```

The code works fine in this case but when replacing  'col1','col2' by the select statement to retrieve columns names the system throws the following error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 39 Column: 40
```

CODE:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT table_name, column_name
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE
      table_name = 'DIM_XYZ'

)
PIVOT
(
  MIN(column_name)
  FOR column_name IN ( 

--code below does not work when plugged in the statement above
              SELECT DISTINCT 
                LISTAGG('''' || column_name || '''', ',') 
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) AS temp_in_statement 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'DIM_XYZ')
 --code above does not work
    )
)
ORDER BY table_name;
----------------
```

do you guys have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The STRING (singular) returned by listagg might LOOK like something you use inside IN() but the truth is it does not work that way. You need to create "dynamic sql" to have the single string "'col1','col2'" to be interpreted as a pair of strings 'col1,'col2'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add dynamic expressions as an input to Pivot table,
You can try something like this  where we retrieve all the columns of the table in a variable via a PL/SQL Block and then pass it in a way to the expected by the Oracle Pivot Table Functionality.

```
SET serveroutput ON;


    DECLARE 
    sqlquery VARCHAR(32767);
    cols VARCHAR2(32767);
    BEGIN

      SELECT listagg('''' || column_name || '''',   ',') within
      GROUP(
      ORDER BY column_name)
      INTO cols
      FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT column_name
         FROM all_tab_columns
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME')
      ;

      sqlquery := '      
    SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT table_name, column_name
      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
      WHERE
          table_name = ''TABLE_NAME''
    )
    PIVOT
    (
      MIN(column_name)
      FOR column_name IN ( 
            ''||cols||''
        )
      )
      ORDER BY table_name';

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlquery);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery;

    END;
    /
```