# Oracle SQL Transpose for non aggregate values

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table...

`SELECT * FROM ALLERGIES;`

Results in:

`Name | Alergy  | Alergy Desc       | Value
John | Gluten  | Gluten Products   | Yes
John | Dairy   | Milk, Cheese etc  | No
Mary | Peanuts | Any kind peanuts  | Yes
Dave | Gluten  | Gluten Products   | No
Dave | Peanuts | Any kind peanuts  | Yes`

And I want it to look like this...

`Name | Dairy | Gluten | Peanuts | ...
Dave | NULL   | No     | Yes     |
John | No     | Yes    | NULL    |
Mary | NULL   | NULL   | Yes     |
.
.
.`

In other words, maintain a distinct list of names on the leftmost column (A-Z), with alergy names for column headers L-R, A-Z.

I'm not using any aggregate functions so unfortunately I can't get it to work with PIVOT. There are multiple names and multiple alergies so hand balling in all the values to satisfy the `IN (x,y,z)` of the PIVOT method doesn't suit here even if I could manufacture some form of aggregate.

Any ideas?

**Side note:**
I've dropped the allergy desc in the request to remove a level of difficulty but ideally it would be 'Alergy - Alergy Desc' for each column header instance.

**Edit:**
Updated title to explicitly state non aggregate values rather than solution without aggregation.

Comment: You need to get the list of allergens (and descriptions) from this table at run-time; you can't hard-code them into your pivot query? If you don't know the number of result columns before you start then you have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: To get PIVOT to work, use an aggregate function even if you don't need to; `min(value)` is customarily used in this way. Fear not: if there is only one value, then `min(value)` will equal that value, so you will get what you need. Even if you were to avoid the PIVOT operator, you would still need aggregation (like `min(value)`) to do the pivoting "the old way", with what's called conditional aggregation.

Comment: The other issue is the large number of allergies... you are, then, best off not doing the pivoting in SQL at all, and instead use the pivoting capabilities of your reporting application (you ARE using one, right?)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @mathguy, I have used aggregate as you suggested, but the large numbers of dynamic values to be used as columns make using MAX(value) FOR X IN(val1,val2) difficult as I can't hardcode those values in. And, yes, I am using a reporting application but specifically I want this to output the desired results from SQL.

Comment: @AJQShake - OK, but then your problem is not "transpose **without aggregate**" - aggregation is not the issue. You will need to use dynamic SQL; that is generally considered a weak approach, and it requires advanced knowledge of PL/SQL. Are you ready to meet that challenge? Why not do it from the reporting application?

Comment: @mathguy - I don't want to do this in the reporting application for a number of complicated reasons but I essentially want the finished query to be dropped into a number of different resources/setups without any configuration needed. Thanks for your help. I'll look into Dynamic SQL. An admin could mark this as a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030522/pivot-does-not-work-when-using-a-nested-select-in-sql as I've incorrectly titled it.